# How to implement Spock Parameterized test best practice?

Tags: spock, shared, unroll

I have a test spec, which can be run with a unique data set. The best practice for this is a bit unclear. How should the code below be modified to run with:

```
@Stepwise
class marktest extends ShopBootStrap  {

   private boolean useProductionUrl = false

   def "Can Access Shop DevLogin page"() {
       // DevStartLogin: 'New OE Start' button click
       setup:
           println System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver")
       when:
           to ShopDevStartPage
       then:
           at ShopDevStartPage
   }

   def "on start enrollment, select 'United States' and click 'continue' button"() {
       when: "enter Sponsor ID and click New OE Start"
           to ShopDevStartPage
           sponsorId.value(ShopDevStartPage.SPONSORID)
           NewOEButton.click()
       then:
           waitFor { NewEnrollmentPage }
   }
}
```

1) data set 1

```
private boolean useProductionUrl = false
protocol = System.getProperty("protocol") ?: "https"
baseDomain = System.getProperty("base.url") ?: "beta.com"
testPassword = System.getProperty("test.password") ?: "dontyouwish"
```

2) data set 2

```
private boolean useProductionUrl = true
protocol = System.getProperty("protocol") ?: "https"
baseDomain = System.getProperty("base.url") ?: "production.com"
testPassword = System.getProperty("test.password") ?: "dywyk"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to make a test depend on data, use a `where` block, possibly together with the `@Unroll` annotation.

However, your case is simply not the best example for a data driven test.
The `baseDomain` and `protocol` should rather be set in the `GebConfig.groovy`, similar to the snippets you provided.
Refer to [this section in the Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#configuration), as that is what you are using.

Simple example (in GebConfig.groovy):

```
environments {
  production {
    baseUrl = "https://production.com"
  }
  beta {
    baseUrl = "https://beta.com"
  }
}
```

If done this way, your individual tests does not need to care about the environment, as this is already built into Geb.
For example when navigating to pages, their base URL is automatically set.
You did not provide that part of the code in your example (how the pages are defined), so I cannot help you with that directly.

Now, in your case, as far as the "password" is concerned, you could read that from an environment variable or system property, that you set close to where you configure Geb with `geb.env` or `geb.build.baseUrl` system properties.
Note I am just considering this for practial reasons without any regards towards secrecy of the password.

You would pick up the variable in the page class that uses it.
Example code in page class:

```
static content = {
    //...
    passwordInput = { $('input[type="password"]') }
    //...
}

void enterPassword() {
    passwordInput.value(System.getProperty('test.password'))
}
```

To make this work, you need to start your test with the system properties set to correct values.

E.g. if starting directly from the command line, you would add parameters `-Dgeb.env=beta -Dtest.password=dontyouwish`.
If running from a Gradle task, you would need to add appropriate `systemProperty` keys and values to that task.
If running from IDE, refer to your IDEs documentation on how to set Java system properties when running a program.

Comment: so, to simplify, let's say a loop is needed to iterate through running this with `baseDomain` , `protocol`, etc set in `GebConfig.groovy`,to different values twice. How can this be done ?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example and more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the `gebConfig.groovy` example. Can you elaborate on how this can be run twice? i.e. run the test spec for production and beta?

Comment: How are you starting your tests in the first place? The answer here really depends on your overall setup. You could create Gradle tasks, for beta and production, and have a task that depends on both...

Comment: Currently running in Intellij. I'm not clear on  starting directly from the command line? How would parameters be added, which reference what is in GebConfig.groovy (i.e. production or beta environment?                                                                             
        For example:   -Dgeb.env=beta -Dtest.password=dontyouwish.

Comment: Parameters passed to Java via the `-D` switch are referred to as "System Properties". I think you might want to give this a try: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206245939-How-can-I-set-defaults-for-test-configurations-

Comment: If you want to run it anywhere else besides in IntelliJ, then the command line is probably your best option. Your build tool presumably has a way to get there.